# Why strcmp function is not comparing the received command from the user with LIST ( without strcmp the function is working )

Tags: c, sockets, strcmp

I am new to socket programming, I am writing an FTP server without the client
I have to access the server using netcat localhost port

```
void do_job(int fd)
{
    i,client;
    char command[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    while((client =recv(fd, command, strlen(command), 0)) >0 )
    {
                
        if (strcmp(command,"LIST") ==0)
        {
        }
```

in the main function :

```
if ((pid=fork()) == 0) {
    close(listenfd);
    do_job(fd);
    printf("Child finished their job!\n");
    close(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `recv()` doesn't add a null terminator to the buffer. `strcmp()` requires the strings to be null terminated.

Comment: Also, the `LIST` command will be followed by `\r\n`, but you're not comparing with that.

Comment: `strlen(command)` requires that `command` have a null terminator. You should use `sizeof(command)` there.

Comment: what should i do to  get a string from the user and compare it with LIST

Comment: It seems like you need to bone up on the basics of C strings before attacking a complex application like an FTP server.

Comment: `recv()` returns the length of the input that it read. So you can use that to add a null terminator to the string.

Comment: Is this implementing the real FTP protocol (RFC 959)? Or just a simple protocol you're designing yourself as an exercise?

Comment: this is a simple FTP server, the user can use commands like LIST to list the content of the directory and Get to get the files names and their size

Comment: If you send 'LIST', 'L', 'LI', 'LIS', and 'LIST' are all possible buffer contents after one successful recv() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a null terminator to the string in order to use `strcmp()`. Also, if they type a line ending with newline, that character will be in `command`, so you need to include it in the string you compare with.

When calling `recv()` the third argument should be the max amount you can store in the buffer. `strlen(command)` returns the length of a string that's already in the buffer, but you haven't initialized it. You can use `DEFAULT_BUFLEN`, and subtract 1 to allow room for the null terminator that will be added.

```
void do_job(int fd)
{
    i,client;
    char command[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    while((client =recv(fd, command, DEFAULT_BUFLEN - 1, 0)) >0 )
    {
        command[client] = '\0'; // add null terminator
        if (strcmp(command,"LIST\n") ==0)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Just note the loop may not work in all cases as `recv` returns number of bytes read from the stream. In case you receive `LIST` string in multiple `recv` calls, your code will not be reliable even if your TCP stream will look just fine.

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect: fails to handle TCP octet streaming.

Comment: I've consciously decided to ignore that, as the solution to it will be much to complicated for a beginner problem.

Comment: If they're using netcat as the client, it's relatively safe to assume that each input line will be sent as a unit, and the receiving system won't split it up for no reason.

Comment: @Barmar maybe but, nevertheless, the code is just not fit for purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The code has numerous issues. You're appying `strlen` to an uninitialized array. This is undefined behavior, which in actual practice could return anything from 0 to values in excess of the array size.

The `recv` function fills buffers from a byte stream; it doesn't return null-terminated strings, and doesn't extract lines from the stream. `recv` will happily read a fragment of the network input stream which starts in the middle of one command and ends in the middle of another one.

In the actual FTP protocol, a command will not be a null-terminated string anyway.

> FTP commands are "Telnet strings" terminated by the "Telnet end of
> line code" [RFC 959, 4.1.3, P. 34]

Basically the whole approach is too simplistic to be workable; the program needs some sort of character stream abstraction over the network input, so that it can parse the protocol properly.

Comment: He's not implementing the actual FTP protocol. He's implementing a toy protocol that he called FTP.